# mongoose populate a deep path

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to use populate api to get inbox data populated by user model?

Here shcemas:

```
const inboxSchema = Schema({
  messageList: [{
    from: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'user' },
    to: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, require: true, ref: 'user' },
  }]
})

const userSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, require: true },
})
```

expected result, eg:

```
{
    "messageList": [
        {
            from: {
                _id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                name: 'Smith'
            },
            to: {
                _id: zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz,
                name: 'John'
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use The [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) Query like Below."

```
.populate([{
    path:"messageList.from"
    select:"_id name"
},{
    path:"messageList.to"
    select:"_id name"
}])
```